# array index for iphone

Tags: iphone

```
 NSString *list = @"Norman, Stanley, Fletcher";
NSMutableArray *a2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//a2= [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];


[a2 addObject:list];
//NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];

NSLog(@"array is  %@",a2);
NSLog(@"array o  %@",a2[0]);
```

how to get a2[0]=Norman , a2[1]=stanley???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying this

```
   NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
   [a2 addObject:list];
    NSLog(@"array o  %@", [a2 objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: g8 it worked though i hav seperate issue i think i should start new thread :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a mutable array you have to add objects to the array. You can't set the mutable array equal to a normal array (its returned by componentsSeparatedByString:)

```
NSString *list = @"Norman, Stanley, Fletcher";
NSMutableArray *a2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[a2 addObjectsFromArray:[list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]];

NSLog(@"array is  %@",a2);
NSLog(@"array o  %@",[a2 objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: thanks but still a2[0]= NSCFArray??
i want to get a2[0] as Norman

Comment: Just changed my code above. You have to use objectAtIndex: instead of the brackets.